# Set Method Order in Visual Studio 2019 IntelliCode Suggestion?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

For instance

[image]

LogError is the first in "Star IntelliCode Suggestion," despite Log being first without Star Suggestion.

I'd rather not disable these Star Suggestions altogether because they can be quite useful, but I don't understand why they aren't ordered the same way as the non-starred auto completes.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering is based on the context where you get the completion. The most likely option is presented at the top of the completion list. In a different context the order changes.